# SQL Server 2014 - Update Multiple Rows based on if exists and parameters from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with BookingIDs
I have a table with FormatIDs
I have a table with Shipments

Here the DLL to build them if somebody want to test

```
CREATE TABLE PI_Booking (
  ID int NULL,
  UID nvarchar(50) NULL,
  BookingID nvarchar(20) NULL,
  DayUsed date NULL,
  PI_Format nvarchar(10) NULL
)
INSERT INTO PI_Booking (ID,UID, BookingID,DayUsed,PI_Format)
VALUES(5,'test','123456','2018-06-06','2')
VALUES(6,'test','123457',NULL,NULL)
VALUES(7,'test','123458',NULL,NULL)
VALUES(8,'test','123459',NULL,NULL)
VALUES(9,'test','123460',NULL,NULL)
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PI_Formats (
  PI_Format nvarchar(1) NULL,
  PI_Code nvarchar(1) NULL,
  RegNo nvarchar(20) NULL
)
INSERT INTO PI_Formats (PI_Format, PI_Code, RegNo)
VALUES('1','S','DCXX001')
VALUES('2','M','DCXX002')
VALUES('3','L','DCXX003')
VALUES('4','E','DCXX004')
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Shipments(
  ID int NULL,
  SStatus nvarchar(50) NULL,
  PI_Format nvarchar(1) NULL,
  BookingID nvarchar(20) NULL,
  AutNo     nvarchar(10) NULL
)
INSERT INTO Shipments (ID,SStatus, PI_Format)
VALUES(35,'Departure','1')
VALUES(36,'Departure','1')
VALUES(39,'Departure','2')
VALUES(40,'Hold','2')
VALUES(41,'Departure','2')
VALUES(43,'Hold','1')
VALUES(46,'Departure','1')
VALUES(48,'Departure','2')
VALUES(51,'Hold','3')
VALUES(52,'Departure','4')
VALUES(54,'Departure','1')
```

I have to assign the `PI_Booking.BookingID` and the `PI_Formats.AutNo` to shipment in Departure Status 
but `BookingID`has to change every day and has to be different for each `FormatID`

From Shipments we see that today's Shipments with 'Departure' Status have PI_Format 1, 2 and 4

My Idea was to put into a temp table the above three values, 1,2,4 with a query like this:

```
insert into @TempTable (PI_Format) 
select distinct PI_Format 
FROM Shipments 
WHERE SStatus='Departure'
```

then have to assign the date and PI_Format to the PI_Booking table:

I was wondering something like:

```
if not exists 
(select 1 from PI_Booking 
 where DayUsed =cast(getUTCDATE() as date) 
 and PI_Format=@TempTable.PI_Format)

BEGIN
  update PI_Booking.DayUsed=GETUTCDATE(), PI_Format=@TempTable.PI_Format 
  ...to the first unused record, thus where ID=5
END
```

and then for all the (3) PI_Format Values
therefore PI_Booking Table at should looks like:

```
|  ID   | UID  | BookingID |   DayUsed   | PI_Format | 
|   5   | test | 123456    |  2018-06-06 |      2    | 
|   6   | test | 123457    |  2018-06-07 |      1    | 
|   7   | test | 123458    |  2018-06-07 |      2    | 
|   8   | test | 123459    |  2018-06-07 |      4    | 
|   9   | test | 123460    |     NULL    |    NULL   |
```

but I do not know how to write this step, and I think that there should be a more elegant way to solve this issue..

then to assign PI_Booking.BookingID and the PI_Formats.AutNo seems me quite easy: 
I can join the 3 tables using PI_Format and DayUsed as join field

Can suggest a solution, or at least the path?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of the expected output?

Comment: Also, your insert statements for Shipments are expecting two columns but three values are specified.

Comment: fixed third input field and added expected output Thanks!